# Cluster graph of bordered countries?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, geography

I'm looking for a way to create a nodal graph of clusters of countries that border each other.

I have the code for finding the bordering countries of, say, Germany:

```
Entity["Country", "Germany"][EntityProperty["Country", "BorderingCountries"]]
```

> (Austria | Belgium | Czech Republic | Denmark | France | Luxembourg | Netherlands | Poland | Switzerland)

and France:

```
Entity["Country", "France"][EntityProperty["Country", "BorderingCountries"]]
```

> (Andorra | Belgium | Germany | Italy | Luxembourg | Monaco | Spain | Switzerland)

So from this information I want to create something that looks like this:
[image: here]

Is this possible? How would I do this?

Comment: See also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75677/coloring-a-map-of-georegions

Answer (score 21):

### France and Germany

```
countries = {Entity["Country", "France"], Entity["Country", "Germany"]};
data = EntityValue[countries, "BorderingCountries", "EntityAssociation"];

vertices = Keys[data];
edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ Join @@ Thread /@ Normal[data];

SimpleGraph[Graph[vertices, edges], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

(It's too bad the default layout places Belgium right on the edge connecting France and Germany.)

### All Countries

```
data = EntityValue["Country", "BorderingCountries", "EntityAssociation"];

vertices = Keys[data];
edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ Join @@ Thread /@ DeleteMissing[Normal[data], 1];

SimpleGraph[Graph[vertices, edges]]
```

[image]

If you want to add coordinates:

```
pos = Reverse[EntityValue["Country", "Position"][[All, 1]], {2}];

SimpleGraph[Graph[vertices, edges], VertexCoordinates -> pos, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

If you want a background in your `Graph` object:

```
background = {EdgeForm[Thin], LightGray, EntityValue["Country", "Polygon"]};

SimpleGraph[
  Graph[vertices, edges], 
  VertexCoordinates -> pos, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  VertexSize -> 20,
  VertexStyle -> Green, 
  EdgeStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
  Prolog -> background
]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and simple!

Comment: For some reason I get an error when this runs.

Comment: This returns an error of Join::heads: Heads List and Rule at positions 1 and 99 are expected to be the same. for me.

Comment: See my edit. Had to take `Normal[data]` to `DeleteMissing[Normal[data], 1]`. For whatever reason Hong Kong and Macau now point to `Missing["NotApplicable"]` instead of `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how to combine them though.

```
list = CanonicalName[
       Entity["Country", "Germany"][
        EntityProperty["Country", "BorderingCountries"]]];

    StarGraph[Length@list + 1, 
     VertexLabels -> 
      Table[i -> Placed[Join[{"Germany"}, list][[i]], Center], {i, 
        Length@list + 1}], ImageSize -> 450, VertexSize -> 0.6, 
     VertexShapeFunction -> "Capsule", VertexStyle -> LightGreen]
```

[image]