# How to style land and borders in GeoRegionValuePlot

Tags: style, geographics

I am trying to create a GeoRegionValuePlot-like graph with:

1. Land coloured Red or Blue, depending on a numerical value.
2. Thin black borders around the states.
3. A white background, showing nothing but the states I want to draw.

My closest attempt is to not use GeoRegionValuePlot at all:

```
GeoGraphics[{
  (* Want Red *)
  Polygon[Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"NewSouthWales", "Australia"}]],
  (* Want Blue *) 
  Polygon[Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Victoria", "Australia"}]],      
  EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}]
}, 
  GeoBackground -> White]
```

[image]

With `GeoRegionValuePlot`, the best that I can do so far is `GeoBackground -> None`, or `GeoBackground -> {"CountryBorders", "Border" -> Black}`, but the latter option draws things other than the two states that I want. For example,

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[{Entity[
    "AdministrativeDivision", {"NewSouthWales", "Australia"}] -> 1.5,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Victoria", "Australia"}] -> 2}, 
 GeoBackground -> {"CountryBorders", "Border" -> Black},]
```

**Q: How to custom style the land and borders of a `GeoRegionValuePlot`?**

Answer (score 1):

At the last second, I came across a solution thanks to modifying [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75700/87750). I'm posting it here in case others need this kind of visualtion.

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Red, x < 2}}, Blue]; (* Rule: Red if val < 2, Blue otherwise *)

states = {Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"NewSouthWales", "Australia"}], 
          Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Victoria", "Australia"}]};
vals = {1, 3};

GeoGraphics[MapThread[{EdgeForm[Black], f[#1], Polygon[#2]} &, {vals, states}], 
 GeoBackground -> White]
```

[image]

If you want the colours to have `Opacity[1]` (and for more general styling), use `GeoStyling[]`. For example,

```
GeoGraphics[
MapThread[{GeoStyling[f[#1]], EdgeForm[Directive[White, Thick]], Polygon[#2]} &,
 {vals, states}
  ], 
 GeoBackground -> White
]
```

[image]